# The reference behavior of individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container?

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

What does this mean "In other words, the reference behavior of arrays is defined in an element-by-element basis; the reference behavior of individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container."

How individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container? I was going thorough [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) and i am confused what it means?

```
<?php
/* Assignment of scalar variables */
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$c = $b;
$c = 7; //$c is not a reference; no change to $a or $b

/* Assignment of array variables */
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
/* The contents of $arr are changed even though it's not a reference! */
?>
```

Comment: `$arr2 = $arr;` You don't assign it by reference, but the array contains an element which has the same reference as `$a` and this still applies even though you assign the array by value.

Comment: Did not know about this at all. Will be glad to see some clarification

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 got it somewhat you are saying. more explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if you use some ASCII art you might understand it better:

#### First example:

```
//Line 01
$a = 1;

----------

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
```

```
//Line 02
$b = &$a;

----------

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
                                  ^
┌──────┐                          │
│  $b  │   ───────────────────────┘ 
└──────┘
```

```
//Line 03
$c = $b;

----------

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
                                  ^
┌──────┐                          │
│  $b  │   ───────────────────────┘ 
└──────┘                      

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $c  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
```

```
//Line 04
$c = 7;

----------

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
                                  ^
┌──────┐                          │
│  $b  │   ───────────────────────┘ 
└──────┘                      

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $c  │   ─────────────────>  │  7  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
```

Now as you can see when you assign a variable by reference and you change it, it will also change the value for the other variable. Here for example `$a` and `$b`, if you assign 5 to `$b`, `$a` will also point to 5, vice versa.

But you didn't assigned `$b` to `$c` by reference (you made a normal by value assignment), so if you change the value of `$c` it won't change the value of `$b` (, or `$a`).

#### Second example:

```
//Line 01
$arr = array(1);

----------

┌───────────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $arr[0]  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└───────────┘                       └─────┘
```

```
//Line 02
$a = &$arr[0];

----------

┌───────────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $arr[0]  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└───────────┘                       └─────┘
                                       ^
┌──────┐                               │
│  $a  │   ────────────────────────────┘ 
└──────┘
```

```
//Line 03
$arr2 = $arr;

----------

┌───────────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $arr[0]  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└───────────┘                       └─────┘
                                       ^
┌──────┐                               │
│  $a  │   ────────────────────────────┤ 
└──────┘                               │
                                       │
┌────────────┐                         │
│  $arr2[0]  │   ──────────────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

```
//Line 04
$arr2[0]++;

----------

┌───────────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $arr[0]  │   ─────────────────>  │  2  │
└───────────┘                       └─────┘
                                       ^
┌──────┐                               │
│  $a  │   ────────────────────────────┤ 
└──────┘                               │
                                       │
┌────────────┐                         │
│  $arr2[0]  │   ──────────────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

Now here comes the line what the manual is trying to explain:

```
$arr2 = $arr;
```

Even though you don't assign the array `$arr` by reference to `$arr2`, the array still holds an element which points to a reference! And that reference will still be in `$arr2`, so the first element of the second array also points to the reference as `$arr[0]` and `$a` does.

---

Maybe if you see the difference when an array is assigned by reference and when an array holds an element with a reference you understand it better:

#### Array assigned by reference:

```
//Line 01
$arr1 = [1, 1, 1];

----------

┌─────────┐                            
│  $arr1  │         
└─────────┘                       
     │
     │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐
                 │   Array    │          ┌─────┐  
                 │ container: │    ┌───> │  1  │
                 ├────────────┤    │     └─────┘
                 │    [0]     │ ───┘
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  1  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐
                 └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐ 
                                   └───> │  1  │
                                         └─────┘
```

```
//Line 02
$arr2 = &$arr1;

----------

┌─────────┐                            
│  $arr1  │         
└─────────┘                       
     │
     │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐
                 │   Array    │          ┌─────┐  
                 │ container: │    ┌───> │  1  │
                 ├────────────┤    │     └─────┘
                 │    [0]     │ ───┘
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  1  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐
     ┌─────────> └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐ 
     │                             └───> │  1  │
     │                                   └─────┘
┌─────────┐                            
│  $arr2  │         
└─────────┘
```

```
//Line 03 & 04
$arr2[0] = 2;
$arr2[1] = 2;

----------

┌─────────┐                            
│  $arr1  │         
└─────────┘                       
     │
     │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐
                 │   Array    │          ┌─────┐  
                 │ container: │    ┌───> │  2  │
                 ├────────────┤    │     └─────┘
                 │    [0]     │ ───┘
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  2  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐
     ┌─────────> └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐ 
     │                             └───> │  1  │
     │                                   └─────┘
┌─────────┐                            
│  $arr2  │         
└─────────┘
```

So as you can see here, since you assigned `$arr1` to `$arr2` by reference they both point to the same array.

#### Array containing a reference:

```
//Line 01
$a = 1;

----------

┌──────┐                       ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ─────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                       └─────┘
```

```
//Line 02
$arr3 = [&$a, 1, 1];

----------

┌──────┐                        ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ──────────────────>  │  1  │
└──────┘                        └─────┘            
                                   ^              
┌─────────┐                        │              
│  $arr3  │                        │              
└─────────┘                        │              
     │                             │              
     │                             │              
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐    │              
                 │   Array    │    │              
                 │ container: │    │              
                 ├────────────┤    │              
                 │    [0]     │ ───┘              
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  1  │  
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘  
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐              
                 └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐  
                                   └───> │  1  │  
                                         └─────┘
```

```
//Line 03
$arr4 = $arr3;

----------

┌──────┐                        ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ──────────────────>  │  1  │ <─────────┐
└──────┘                        └─────┘           │ 
                                   ^              │
┌─────────┐                        │              │
│  $arr3  │                        │              │
└─────────┘                        │              │
     │                             │              │
     │                             │              │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐    │              │
                 │   Array    │    │              │
                 │ container: │    │              │
                 ├────────────┤    │              │
                 │    [0]     │ ───┘              │
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  │
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  1  │  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘  │
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐              │
                 └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐  │
                                   └───> │  1  │  │
                                         └─────┘  │
                                                  │
┌─────────┐                                       │
│  $arr4  │                                       │
└─────────┘                                       │
     │                                            │
     │                                            │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐                   │
                 │   Array    │                   │
                 │ container: │                   │
                 ├────────────┤                   │
                 │    [0]     │ ──────────────────┘
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  1  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐
                 └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐ 
                                   └───> │  1  │
                                         └─────┘
```

```
//Line 03 & 04
$arr4[0] = 2;
$arr4[1] = 2;

----------

┌──────┐                        ┌─────┐      
│  $a  │   ──────────────────>  │  2  │ <─────────┐
└──────┘                        └─────┘           │ 
                                   ^              │
┌─────────┐                        │              │
│  $arr3  │                        │              │
└─────────┘                        │              │
     │                             │              │
     │                             │              │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐    │              │
                 │   Array    │    │              │
                 │ container: │    │              │
                 ├────────────┤    │              │
                 │    [0]     │ ───┘              │
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  │
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  1  │  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘  │
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐              │
                 └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐  │
                                   └───> │  1  │  │
                                         └─────┘  │
                                                  │
┌─────────┐                                       │
│  $arr4  │                                       │
└─────────┘                                       │
     │                                            │
     │                                            │
     └─────────> ┌────────────┐                   │
                 │   Array    │                   │
                 │ container: │                   │
                 ├────────────┤                   │
                 │    [0]     │ ──────────────────┘
                 ├────────────┤          ┌─────┐  
                 │    [1]     │ ───────> │  2  │
                 ├────────────┤          └─────┘
                 │    [2]     │ ───┐
                 └────────────┘    │     ┌─────┐ 
                                   └───> │  1  │
                                         └─────┘
```

So as you can see here even though you assigned `$arr3` to `$arr4` by value, not by reference! The array still contains that reference, which is shared with `$a` and `$arr3[0]`.

Comment: @kamlesh.bar Maybe this example makes it a bit more clearer: https://3v4l.org/la5El

Comment: Bravo Man :) got your point completely. Amazed by strange behaviour

Comment: @kamlesh.bar You're welcome. Updated my answer again and made a separate example.